# How to set keep-alive timeout on server-side for ktor (netty)

Tags: java, kotlin, netty, ktor

As I understand *keep-alive timeout* is a server side property. I would like to configure keep-alive timeout in ktor. Here is the server:

```
embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, configure = {..}, ) { ... }
```

I see boolean `tcpKeepAlive` property inside Netty specific configuration. And it definition is:

> If set to true, enables TCP keep alive for connections so all dead
> client connections will be discarded. The timeout period is configured
> by the system so configure your host accordingly.

So for me it is not clear what does it mean **configure your host accordingly.**

I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29749938/3601615 which could tell how to close idle connections. But I have been supposing that it would be enough to use some single property to set keep-alive timeout, and the mentioned solution looks complicated.

I will appreciate any advices how to configure keep-alive timeout in ktor.

Comment: The `tcpKeepAlive` property set to `true` enables the `StandardSocketOptions. SO_KEEPALIVE` option that is described in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/StandardSocketOptions.html?is-external=true#SO_KEEPALIVE

Comment: @AlekseiTirman, maybe you have an idea how is it possible to add custom `childHandler` in `ktor-server-netty:1.6.7`,  I see that in version 2.x the special property `channelPipelineConfig` appeared

Comment: You can do it by configuring a `ServerBootstrap`. Here is an example https://gist.github.com/Stexxe/afcea94a66a0d2d1affdfc3d563438dc.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman thank you, but if I am correct,  the default `NettyChannelInitializer` will override MyHandler https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/9ca85c50e297a2c0a124f11f1c1a453909417ecf/ktor-server/ktor-server-netty/jvm/src/io/ktor/server/netty/NettyApplicationEngine.kt#L144
Maybe we should tune configuration a bit

Comment: Yes, you're right. The handler will be overwritten. Unfortunately, I don't know how to solve your problem with Ktor 1.6.*. In Ktor 2.* you can use `channelPipelineConfig` as you wrote before.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman am I right that `requestReadTimeoutSeconds` can be used as an alternative to keep-alive timeout? With one caveat that it may close not only idle connections but some long processing requests ?

Comment: Seems like you're right.